# can I save response (specifically co-ordinates) from here.com using Geocoder API?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I am setting up an application and it contains addresses of some people and I would like to find the geo-coordinates (lat, long) from those addresses and store them to my database.

can I query here.com and save it in my DB ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch Geocoder API to download the result of your request.
For example :

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs/{YOUR JOB REQUEST ID}/result?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

For detail information kindly go through the documentation

https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/example-get-results.html